# How to connect to my apache localhost from a different network?

Tags: apache, configuration, connection

I am able to connect it if the two devices are in the same network but for example, if I use 4G on my android and turn of the wifi and try to connect to `http://computer-ip-address` then it just hangs and eventually errors out saying count not connect. The apache server is hosted in my local mac, and I've disabled my firewall temporarily. Any ideas on how to get a device using a different network to connect to my apache server on my local network?

Comment: What kind of router do you have? Try setting it to forward traffic on port 80 to your computer.

Comment: I think I know what you are suggesting but I'm not sure how to make that adjustment.I will see if I can figure out how to forward traffic to port 80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to configure your router so that it will forward port 80 from external to your mac.

Then, you can open `http://your-public-Internet-ip` on your mobile phone, effectively visiting your local web server.

If you don't like to remember your ip address, especially if you are on the go, the answer is dyndns or any free alternative, e.g. http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html.

Using such a service, you will be able to enter `http://yourname.service.com` into your mobile phone. You will either have to configure your router to always tell this service your current IP (check your router for supported services) or run a tiny program on your mac which will handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable port forwarding on your router to forward TCP 80 (and possibly TCP 443 if you are using SSL) to your web servers IP address.

Once done, you should be able to access your site via your routers public IP address.

Take note that of your web server is using a dynamic address provided by DHCP, your IP may change and this would stop it from working. I suggest you give your web server a static IP address to stop this.

You will probably have a dynamic IP on your router as well, so you can request a static one from your ISP or you can sign up for a dynamic DNS service.

If you post the model of your router, we may be able to give you more specific instruction on setting up port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

i hope your httpd.conf is set with port listening to

```
Listen 80
```

also, you can only access your site from your LAN otherwise, your server would need to be reachable from a public IP address, not a private one over an internet 4g connection, that means a diferent network

bonus points, if you try to reach your server from an external address, did you configure portforwarding on your router ?

Comment: Er, yes. That is the question. "Any ideas on how to get a device using a different network to connect to my apache server on my local network?"

Comment: did you configure portforward on your router and did you check your httpd.conf ? it's futile to configure portforwarding and not make apache listen to all IP addresses ? if you modify your httpd.conf, restart your process or service ...

Answer (score 1):

If you could immediately and immediately connect to your `localhost` using your 4G network, then most likely anyone on the internet could do the same. It is important to understand that there are two components to the answer to your question:

- Securing HTTP access (port 80 or whichever) from the internet. You probably don't want to open a wide door to your local network.
- Configuring addressing from your client (in this case your phone) to your local computer (in this case your Mac). If the latter does not have a public IP address, then you will have to configure your client to hit your router instead, and to configure your router to forward accordingly.

Given that this is mostly system configuration work, I'm guessing that [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to find a satisfying answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was going to first try to get a device from different network to connect, then the next step would be user authentication, with some password I only know.